# Codeigniter DB with slug

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm in trouble when trying to get DB data passing **slug** in URL.

```
 public function news($slug = "")
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array("slug", $slug));
        $row = $query->row_array();                    

    }
```

If i try to 'echo' information, e.g `echo $row["message"];` I see blank page. =/

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->get('news', array("slug", $slug))->row_array();
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->where( "slug", $slug)->get('news')->row_array();
var_dump($query);
```

Comment: @jjPeter88 you're welcome , but here instead of thanking you should click the little check icon on the left side of my answer

Answer (score 0):

in my nsh opinion this is not a good idea

```
public function news($slug = "")
```

the only way its acceptable to say that the method parameter can be blank is if the method still works without it. which in this case it won't. 
anyway lets write this out

```
    // the fields you want
    $this->db->select( 'id,and,oh,here,are,some,fields' );
    // the where condition
    $this->db->where( 'slug', $slug);
    // the table name and create the query
    $query = $this->db->get( 'news' );
```

now before sending $query out into the world, make sure it has a record for you by using num_rows()

```
if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) { return $query->row_array(); }

// so you also have the option to check for and return a group of records 
// but the rules this time are one article only, so return false 
else{ return false ; }
```

now in your controller, assuming your model is called something like articles, do it something like this

```
    $slug = 'something that has already been validated' ;

   // if no article came back, do something else
   if( ! $article = $this->articles->news($slug) ) 
{
    // no article came back 
    // show appropriate view 
    $this->_showNoArticleFor($slug) ; 

} 

else{ $this->_showFound($article) ;  }
```

in codeigniter an underscore in the controller method names automatically makes them private so they can't be accessed publicly. in general if a form or search fails - call a separate method that clearly states that something has not been found or its failed. that way you keep your views separate because views change often. otherwise you are piling completely different types of view files inside if conditions and its a mess.